# How to write a recursive function in C# that looks like A(key, B(key, C(key, ValFactory(key))))?

Tags: c#, function, recursion, functional-programming

How do you write a function that has this form:

```
A(key, B(key, C(key, ValFactory(key))))
```

Where A, B, and C have this signature:

```
TResult GetOrAdd(string key, Func<string, TResult> generator);
```

And Valfactory has the signature:

```
TResult Get(string key);
```

The number of "chained" functions has no limit btw, so it can be A, B, or A, B, C, or A, B, C, D, E, etc.

I store the functions A, B, C, etc. in a LinkedList

How do I call them the way I want to?

*Edit* adding some info for clarification:

I need this to implement a multi-level cache.  There are several different caches that all implement the "GetOrAdd" function.  The first level cache is just a ConcurrentDictionary that has the GetOrAdd function already.

The way the cache works is, if the first-level cache does not have an entry for a particular key, it tries looking in the 2nd-level cache.  The 2nd-level cache looks to the 3rd-level cache on a miss, etc.

No cache should have any knowledge of another cache, it should just implement the signature `TResult GetOrAdd(string, Func<string, TResult> functionToCallOnCacheMiss)`

Comment: You should definitely show some code. Otherwise its mind reading.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing each Func in a linked list, why don't you just iterate through the list and call the next func with the previous result?

Comment: That's backwards from what I want - I want the current node to get it's value from the next node in the list

Comment: So loop through the list in reverse order?  I'm still confused at how this is an issue of recursion?!  It sounds more like you are needing a stack / queue of functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little example for it. Instead of using two different delegates, it uses only one to simplify things. It's the user's responsibility to ensure that the last method passed as a parameter won't try to access the queue. It probably can be rearranged, though.

```
public delegate TResult GetOrAdd<TResult>(string key, Queue<GetOrAdd<TResult>> generatorChain);

static T ExecuteChain<T>(string key, params GetOrAdd<T>[] generators)
{
    var queue = new Queue<GetOrAdd<T>>(generators.Skip(1));
    return generators.First()(key, queue);
}

static int A(string key, Queue<GetOrAdd<int>> generatorChain)
{
    var newKey = key.ToUpper();
    //You can perform checks on the queue
    //i.e. if it's empty, throw an exception
    var tempResult = generatorChain.Dequeue()(newKey, generatorChain);
    return tempResult*2;
}

static int B(string key, Queue<GetOrAdd<int>> generatorChain)
{
    var newKey = key.Insert(0, "My string is: ");
    var tempResult = generatorChain.Dequeue()(newKey, generatorChain);
    return tempResult + 1;
}

static int ValFactory(string key, Queue<GetOrAdd<int>> generatorChain)
{
    //Instead of defining another delegate, we just don't use the queue
    //You can still run your checks (i.e. throw exception if not empty)
    return key.GetHashCode();
}
```

And you can call the chain through:

```
var result = ExecuteChain<int>("Hello world", A, B, ValFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given these definitions:

```
public delegate TResult GetOrAdd<TResult>(string key, Func<string, TResult> generator);
public delegate TResult Get<TResult>(string key);
```

You'll need a function like this:

```
public static Func<string, TResult> Chain<TResult>(Get<TResult> last, params GetOrAdd<TResult>[] funcs) {
    if (funcs.Count() == 0) return key => last(key);
    var head = funcs.First();
    var tail = funcs.Skip(1).ToArray();
    return key => head(key, Chain(last, tail));
}
```

To write code like this:

```
var result = Chain(ValFactory, A, B, C)(key);
```

Note that this looks like a type of [chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

**Update**: you can also simplify `Chain` and have the client use the desired parameter ordering with an adapter function:

```
public static GetOrAdd<TResult> Adapt<TResult>(Get<TResult> factory) {
    return (key, next) => factory(key);
}

public static Func<string, TResult> Chain<TResult>(params GetOrAdd<TResult>[] funcs) {
    if (funcs.Count() == 0) return null; // or return key => default(TResult);
    var head = funcs.First();
    var tail = funcs.Skip(1).ToArray();
    return key => head(key, Chain(tail));
}

...

var result = Chain(A, B, C, Adapt(ValFactory))(key);
```

Comment: I will try this approach and see if it works tomorrow, it is midnight here.  Thank you for posting it!  :)